# MS Azure remote back up with SqlPackage

Tags: sql-server, export, azure, bacpac

I wanted to do an export of a .bacpac file from MS Azure database, from local machine, with command like this:

```
sqlpackage.exe /Action:Export /ssn:tcp:<ServerName>.database.windows.net,1433 /sdn:<DatabaseName> /su:<UserName> /sp:<Password> /tf:<TargetFile> /p:Storage=File
```

The DB was apparently found and the tool reported it started extracting the schema from the database, but then it fails:

```
Extracting schema
Extracting schema from database
Time elapsed 00:00:05.17
*** An unexpected failure occurred: .NET Core should not be using a file backed 
model..
```

To my surprise, I couldn't find anything similar on the web. Is this some kind of an MS Azure bug?

Comment: I have the same issue ...

Answer (score 2):

You can remove `/p:Storage=File`. This worked for me.

```
/p:Storage=File : is used to redirect the backing storage for the schema model used during extraction, this helpful with large databases that may cause out-of-memory exception if the default memory location is used.
```

If this is not an issue for you, just omitting the parameter should fix your issue.

Comment: and if it is an issue?

Comment: It seems that the file backed model uses a feature which is only available on the windows platform and in full .NET, not in Core. (https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues/12754) It seems that sqlpackage is only bundled with core which is kind of ... . But perhaps with your approach from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66409710 and a full .NET it could be possible? Perhaps also keep track of this (https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues/12754) as it seems to point to an issue in DacFx

Comment: but if you can't use the file option in .net core, how are you supposed to import very large bacpacs? Since the other option means loading the file to the memory, so what happens when the file is larger than the available ram?

Comment: the only way I can think of right now is not to use sqlpackage and kind of follow what this guy did https://thomaslarock.com/2017/04/view-bacpac-files-using-one-weird-trick/

Comment: but this question is about sqlpackage as well. Also, I need to do it with code, not manually